How to suppress standard output when using `osascript` to type a keystroke
I'm planning to create an AppleScript script to "type" a string on the command line, but my script:
cmd="echo 'abc'"
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"${cmd}\""

always shows the standard output, even if I use >/dev/null 2>&1, as seen in the screenshot below:

Is there any solution to suppress the standard output and just only "type" the string ?

update 1
if the cmd variable is a very long string, the "1st" output shows 57 chars maximum ( as below ). Is there any solution to "mark" the first output to 0 char?
cmd='very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-very-long-string'
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"${cmd}\""



update 2
thanks @jaume for the solution, using bash -c "... &" works perfect ! :)
details:
$ cmd='something'
$ bash -c "osascript -e \"tell application \\\"System Events\\\" to keystroke \\\"${cmd}\\\"\" &"


working with fzf ( source code ), demo link: https://streamable.com/8qkgza

Why is output shown twice?
That's not osascript's standard output what you see but System Events typing "echo 'abc'".
You see it twice because System Events types it while osascript is running. When osascript finishes and returns control to the shell, the shell displays the new prompt, and it also displays any input typed previously, in this case "echo 'abc'".
That is, there is no standard output to supress, it is just the way the shell works.
This behavior is not exclusive to osascript, for example, if you compress a large file with the zip command and type something before zip is done, the text is also shown twice.
How can the "double output" be suppressed?
You can suppress the output by slightly delaying when the string is written to the Terminal window. This can be achieved with a shell function:

Open Terminal.

Type the following text and press Enter:
 function t { zsh -c "osascript -e \"do shell script \\\"/bin/sleep 1\\\"\" -e \"tell application \\\"System Events\\\" to keystroke \\\"${cmd}\\\"\" &"; }

You can replace zsh with bash in the function above if prefer the latter:
 function t { bash -c "osascript -e \"do shell script \\\"/bin/sleep 1\\\"\" -e \"tell application \\\"System Events\\\" to keystroke \\\"${cmd}\\\"\" &"; }

(Both functions are fully equivalent and can be used interchangeably with both zsh and bash.)

Define cmd (if you don't, the function won't type anything):
 cmd="echo 'abc'"


Run the function:
 t



Now, t will return immediately and then the text will be added to the current line.
The function works with macOS's built-in shells zsh and bash.
You can add the function to your startup shell file so that you don't have to type it everytime you open Terminal:

For zsh, add it to a file named .zshrc in your home folder. To open .zshrc, type open -a TextEdit ~/.zshrc. After adding the line, save the modified file with ⌘S and quit TextEdit with ⌘Q.
For bash, add it to a file named .bashrc in your home folder. To open .bashrc, type open -a TextEdit ~/.bashrc. After adding the line, save the modified file with ⌘S and quit TextEdit with ⌘Q.

How does the function work?
The function runs zsh (or bash, if you chose the second function) to send the osascript command to the background (that's done with the & at the end of the funtion).
osascript first waits half a second (so that the function returns control to the shell) and then types the string.
How can I rename the function?
I called the function t, but you can rename it by replacing the t in function t, for example, function typecmd.

thanks, please check the latest update.I've tried with very-long-string as cmd variable, and found it shows only 57 chars maximum, any solution to mark 1st output to 0 char ?

@Marslo Thanks for updating the question, I found a way to supress the first output by defining a shell function. Could you test it and report back? If it works, I'd appreciate it if you marked my answer as accepted. Thanks in advance.

thanks @jaume, using bash -c ".. &" works like a charm !! I've updated the question, and you can check the demo video at https://streamable.com/8qkgza

I'm glad it works! And thank you for expanding your question with links to the code and demo video, very interesting.

thank you again. I'm just a lazy guy at typing :)
